# METEOR ERROR : ENOENT: NOSUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY. OPEN

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

[image]

I have a problem when a create a new app (meteor creates app) or when a run meteor (meteor) a received this message and I don't understand what's the problem.
but this error is done just today and yesterday is functioning correctly with no error.

Comment: looks like your package.json is missing something.. (did you recently add anything?) .. double check.. also it helps to ensure you have the latest version of npm (or use yarn!)..

Comment: haw do i update the version of npm

Comment: npm install -g npm@latest

Comment: (type that into the terminal window..  should've added that..)